# Drawing a sequence diagram for a "View posts in a section" use case

Tags: uml, domain-model, use-case, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

As title says, I'm currently working on an alaysis model for a little website similar to Reddit for academic purposes.

I have one use cases written like this (They're not in English so they may not have been translated accurately):

**Name**: View Section

1. The user opens the page related to a specific section
2. The system displays informations about the specified section:

   - Name of the section
   - Brief description
   - Picture of the section
3. The system displays all the posts submitted into the section
4. The user sees section informations and posts on his web browser

The use cases begins with the opening of the page because the user may reach the section in many ways (button, link, manually type the URL, search engine..)

There's one similar use cases for "View User Profile" which acts basically the same as this.

This is the Class diagram:

[image]

This is the sequence diagram for the "View Section" use case:

[image]

The fact is, I have no idea if this sequence diagram is correct: there are so few sequence diagrams involving read operations that I don't know if i'm doing the right thing. My main concerns are the followings:

- SectionPage creates ViewSectionControl but does not send any message to it. Is it still semantically correct?
- Is it correct to "create" a Section object? We are trying to retrieve a Section, not create one
- I wrote "getInfo" instead of calling getters for each section attribute. I also called "getPosts" to make explicit the fact that I also want the posts that the section aggregates. I'm not sure about the correctness of this one.
- In general, there's something I could improve out of this sequence diagram/use case?

Comment: I think I'd get the gist of the diagram, but it's probably somewhat misleading (e.g. your concern about ViewSectionControl creating a Section instance - that's probably not how it happens). The thing is, with these diagrams, you're trying to communicate a flow of a process, not to show every detail, so you don't have to show when and how each object is created if it's not really relevant. Your "getInfo" and "getPosts" are fine, just explain in the accompanying text that these stand for a series of calls.

Comment: But ultimately - and this might save you some work - if the sequence is not particularly complicated, or is not really an important aspect of the system to understand, just don't draw the diagram. I mean, your audience (the people who will read this - so, other developers) can look at the code (or even at the page at runtime), and figure out - oh, the page has a section control, and it gets data from some object representing the section. Unless there's something extra there, something they wouldn't anticipate or that they would find tricky, the value of the diagram is marginal. So just skip it